# SVG blurry when resizing

Tags: css, svg

I am using an svg from FlatIcons, When I import it and dont mess with the height/width it looks fine (but is too big) but when I start to reduce its size the borders become blurry and are no longer sharp.

e.g. https://codepen.io/geraintf/pen/ZoaPPW

What is going on? How can I scale an SVG to avoid this?

The SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 52.966 52.966" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52.966 52.966;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M51.704,51.273L36.845,35.82c3.79-3.801,6.138-9.041,6.138-14.82c0-11.58-9.42-21-21-21s-21,9.42-21,21s9.42,21,21,21
    c5.083,0,9.748-1.817,13.384-4.832l14.895,15.491c0.196,0.205,0.458,0.307,0.721,0.307c0.25,0,0.499-0.093,0.693-0.279
    C52.074,52.304,52.086,51.671,51.704,51.273z M21.983,40c-10.477,0-19-8.523-19-19s8.523-19,19-19s19,8.523,19,19
    S32.459,40,21.983,40z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: may this post help : https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/32100/quality-loss-when-scaling-down-svgs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Looks okay to me. Also, that svg is wonky. Why all the empty `<g>` elements? And it's basically a circle and a line. Could be much cleaner.